# Conversion std::string to char

Tags: c++

What is wrong?

```
std::string _text = asLowerCaseString(text);
for(uint8_t i = 0; i < _text.length(); i++)
    {
    char t = _text;
    if(t != '-' && t != '.' && !(t >= 'a' && t <= 'z'))
        {
        _text.erase(i, 1);
        i--;
        }
    }

std::string words []= {".net","no-ip", ".net", ".com", ".com.br", ".org", ".pl", ".net"};
int ii, length;
length = sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]);
for(ii=0; ii < int(length); ii++)
    {
    if (int(_text.find(words[ii])) > 0 || _text == words[ii])
        {
        return false;
        break;
        }
    }
```

Line Error

```
char t = _text;
```

Error

> There is no conversion function "std :: string" a "char" suitable

I'm using msvc 2012, this code works fine under linux compiler but not windows.

Comment: No no no no no. Don't write code like this. :(

Comment: On what line does the error occur? We're not mind readers, you know!

Comment: This line -> char t = _text;

Comment: I highly doubt that `std::string _text = ...;` followed by `char t = _text;` would compile with **any** compiler.

Comment: @dohdle You've malformed the error message, is it hard to press Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V?

Comment: `int ii, length;
length = sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]);
for(ii=0; ii < int(length); ii++)`
This is offensive. I'm offended.

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry, the original text is in spanish

Answer (score 2):

There is no conversion from string to char

```
char t = _text;
```

should be replaced by

```
char t = _text[i];
```

Comment: Already tried it. Error: != : 'char []'  It differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

Comment: That's impossible given the code posted.

Comment: @dohdle Then, the issue is **not** in the code you posted. I have copied your code snippet (excluding the usage of `asLowerCaseString`, since you didn't provide an implementation for it), and it compiles just fine.